# Getting better performance with JpaRepository.saveAll()

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, kotlin, jdbc

I am using a rest-api which is supposed to import data out of csv files. The uploading and mapping to object part is working, but not the saveAll(), it just takes years to save 130000~ rows to the database (which is running on a mssqlserver) and it should be working with much bigger files in less time.

This is what my data class looks:

```
@Entity
data class Street(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "streetSeq")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "streetSeq", sequenceName = "streetSeq", allocationSize = 1)
        val id: Int,
        val name: String?,
        val municipalityId: Int?
)
```

And im just using the saveAll methode. Everything in the import methode works relativ fast (like 10 seconds) untlis the saveAll()

```
override fun import(file: MultipartFile) {

    val inputStream = file.inputStream
    var import: List<Street> = listOf()
    tsvReader.open(inputStream) {
        val csvContents = readAllWithHeaderAsSequence()
        val dataClasses = grass<ImportStreet>().harvest(csvContents)

        dataClasses.forEach { row ->
            import = import + toStreet(row)
        }
        println("Data Converted")
    }
    streetRepository.saveAll(import)
    inputStream.close()
}
```

I already tried to adjust the application.yml but its not making a big diffrence.

```
   jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        generate_statistics: true
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 1000
```

Comment: First try, add `@Batch` on the entity. If it don't work, look into `Spring-Batch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other comments / awnsers suggested i tried to use spring-batch, but it didnt work out for me (mostly because i didnt know how to pull it off with it)

After trying out more stuff i found jdbcTemplate, which perfectly worked out for me, the inserts are now much faster then with the saveAll()
override fun import(file: MultipartFile) {

```
        val inputStream = file.inputStream
        var import: List<Street> = listOf()
        tsvReader.open(inputStream) {
            val csvContents = readAllWithHeaderAsSequence()
            val dataClasses = grass<ImportStreet>().harvest(csvContents)

            dataClasses.forEach { row ->
                import = import + toStreet(row)
            }
            println("Data Converted")
        }
        batchInsert(import)

        inputStream.close()
    }
```

The batchInstert methode is using the jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() fun

```
fun batchInsert(streets: List<Street>): IntArray? {
            return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
                    "INSERT INTO street (name, municipalityId) VALUES (?, ?)",
                     object: BatchPreparedStatementSetter {
                        @Throws(SQLException::class)
                        override fun setValues(ps: PreparedStatement, i: Int) {
                            ps.setString(1, streets[i].name)
                            streets[i].municipalityId?.let { ps.setInt(2, it) }
                        }
    
                        override fun getBatchSize(): Int {
                            return streets.size
                        }
                    })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the implementaiton fo SimpleJpaRepository it's not doing any kind of batching save, it just saves each entity one by one, that's why it is slow
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/d35ee1a82bf0fdf2de2724a02619eea1cf3c98bd/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L584

```
    Assert.notNull(entities, "Entities must not be null!");

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
```

So try to implement batch save without usage of spring-data-jpa, for example using [spring-batch](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)